# generating all possible kmers in R

Tags: r

I have a vector of letters or symbols, say bases=c('A','T','G','C'), is there a shorter and more efficient way(an existing function)to generate all possible k-mers for a given k, other than using nested for loop or sapply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gtools` has the `permutation` fucntion which allows repeated sampling.

> To use values of n above about 45, you will need to increase R's recursion limit. See the expression argument to the options command for details on how to do this.

```
library(gtools)

bases <- c("A","T","C","G")
permutations(n = length(bases), v = bases, r = 3, repeats.allowed = T)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,] "A"  "A"  "A" 
# [2,] "A"  "A"  "C" 
# [3,] "A"  "A"  "G" 
# [4,] "A"  "A"  "T" 
# [5,] "A"  "C"  "A" 
# [6,] "A"  "C"  "C" 
# [7,] "A"  "C"  "G" 
# [8,] "A"  "C"  "T" 
# [9,] "A"  "G"  "A" 
# [10,] "A"  "G"  "C" 
# [11,] "A"  "G"  "G" 
# [12,] "A"  "G"  "T" 
# [13,] "A"  "T"  "A" 
# [14,] "A"  "T"  "C" 
# [15,] "A"  "T"  "G" 
# [16,] "A"  "T"  "T" 
# [17,] "C"  "A"  "A" 
# [18,] "C"  "A"  "C" 
# [19,] "C"  "A"  "G" 
# [20,] "C"  "A"  "T" 
# [21,] "C"  "C"  "A" 
# [22,] "C"  "C"  "C" 
# [23,] "C"  "C"  "G" 
# [24,] "C"  "C"  "T" 
# [25,] "C"  "G"  "A" 
# [26,] "C"  "G"  "C" 
# [27,] "C"  "G"  "G" 
# [28,] "C"  "G"  "T" 
# [29,] "C"  "T"  "A" 
# [30,] "C"  "T"  "C" 
# [31,] "C"  "T"  "G" 
# [32,] "C"  "T"  "T" 
# [33,] "G"  "A"  "A" 
# [34,] "G"  "A"  "C" 
# [35,] "G"  "A"  "G" 
# [36,] "G"  "A"  "T" 
# [37,] "G"  "C"  "A" 
# [38,] "G"  "C"  "C" 
# [39,] "G"  "C"  "G" 
# [40,] "G"  "C"  "T" 
# [41,] "G"  "G"  "A" 
# [42,] "G"  "G"  "C" 
# [43,] "G"  "G"  "G" 
# [44,] "G"  "G"  "T" 
# [45,] "G"  "T"  "A" 
# [46,] "G"  "T"  "C" 
# [47,] "G"  "T"  "G" 
# [48,] "G"  "T"  "T" 
# [49,] "T"  "A"  "A" 
# [50,] "T"  "A"  "C" 
# [51,] "T"  "A"  "G" 
# [52,] "T"  "A"  "T" 
# [53,] "T"  "C"  "A" 
# [54,] "T"  "C"  "C" 
# [55,] "T"  "C"  "G" 
# [56,] "T"  "C"  "T" 
# [57,] "T"  "G"  "A" 
# [58,] "T"  "G"  "C" 
# [59,] "T"  "G"  "G" 
# [60,] "T"  "G"  "T" 
# [61,] "T"  "T"  "A" 
# [62,] "T"  "T"  "C" 
# [63,] "T"  "T"  "G" 
# [64,] "T"  "T"  "T"
```

To use `combn` you need to do alittle trickery by replicating the `bases` based on the size of k and then wrapping in a unqique.

```
k <- 3
unique(t(combn(rep(bases, k), m = k)))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,] "A"  "T"  "C" 
# [2,] "A"  "T"  "G" 
# [3,] "A"  "T"  "A" 
# [4,] "A"  "T"  "T" 
# [5,] "A"  "C"  "G" 
# [6,] "A"  "C"  "A" 
# [7,] "A"  "C"  "T" 
# [8,] "A"  "C"  "C" 
# [9,] "A"  "G"  "A" 
# [10,] "A"  "G"  "T" 
# [11,] "A"  "G"  "C" 
# [12,] "A"  "G"  "G" 
# [13,] "A"  "A"  "T" 
# [14,] "A"  "A"  "C" 
# [15,] "A"  "A"  "G" 
# [16,] "A"  "A"  "A" 
# [17,] "T"  "C"  "G" 
# [18,] "T"  "C"  "A" 
# [19,] "T"  "C"  "T" 
# [20,] "T"  "C"  "C" 
# [21,] "T"  "G"  "A" 
# [22,] "T"  "G"  "T" 
# [23,] "T"  "G"  "C" 
# [24,] "T"  "G"  "G" 
# [25,] "T"  "A"  "T" 
# [26,] "T"  "A"  "C" 
# [27,] "T"  "A"  "G" 
# [28,] "T"  "A"  "A" 
# [29,] "T"  "T"  "C" 
# [30,] "T"  "T"  "G" 
# [31,] "T"  "T"  "A" 
# [32,] "T"  "T"  "T" 
# [33,] "C"  "G"  "A" 
# [34,] "C"  "G"  "T" 
# [35,] "C"  "G"  "C" 
# [36,] "C"  "G"  "G" 
# [37,] "C"  "A"  "T" 
# [38,] "C"  "A"  "C" 
# [39,] "C"  "A"  "G" 
# [40,] "C"  "A"  "A" 
# [41,] "C"  "T"  "C" 
# [42,] "C"  "T"  "G" 
# [43,] "C"  "T"  "A" 
# [44,] "C"  "T"  "T" 
# [45,] "C"  "C"  "G" 
# [46,] "C"  "C"  "A" 
# [47,] "C"  "C"  "T" 
# [48,] "C"  "C"  "C" 
# [49,] "G"  "A"  "T" 
# [50,] "G"  "A"  "C" 
# [51,] "G"  "A"  "G" 
# [52,] "G"  "A"  "A" 
# [53,] "G"  "T"  "C" 
# [54,] "G"  "T"  "G" 
# [55,] "G"  "T"  "A" 
# [56,] "G"  "T"  "T" 
# [57,] "G"  "C"  "G" 
# [58,] "G"  "C"  "A" 
# [59,] "G"  "C"  "T" 
# [60,] "G"  "C"  "C" 
# [61,] "G"  "G"  "A" 
# [62,] "G"  "G"  "T" 
# [63,] "G"  "G"  "C" 
# [64,] "G"  "G"  "G"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in base R using `expand.grid`

```
> bases=c('A','T','G','C')
> expand.grid(bases, bases, bases)
   Var1 Var2 Var3
1     A    A    A
2     T    A    A
3     G    A    A
4     C    A    A
5     A    T    A
6     T    T    A
7     G    T    A
8     C    T    A
9     A    G    A
10    T    G    A
11    G    G    A
12    C    G    A
13    A    C    A
14    T    C    A
15    G    C    A
16    C    C    A
17    A    A    T
18    T    A    T
19    G    A    T
20    C    A    T
21    A    T    T
22    T    T    T
23    G    T    T
24    C    T    T
25    A    G    T
26    T    G    T
27    G    G    T
28    C    G    T
29    A    C    T
30    T    C    T
31    G    C    T
32    C    C    T
33    A    A    G
34    T    A    G
35    G    A    G
36    C    A    G
37    A    T    G
38    T    T    G
39    G    T    G
40    C    T    G
41    A    G    G
42    T    G    G
43    G    G    G
44    C    G    G
45    A    C    G
46    T    C    G
47    G    C    G
48    C    C    G
49    A    A    C
50    T    A    C
51    G    A    C
52    C    A    C
53    A    T    C
54    T    T    C
55    G    T    C
56    C    T    C
57    A    G    C
58    T    G    C
59    G    G    C
60    C    G    C
61    A    C    C
62    T    C    C
63    G    C    C
64    C    C    C
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `permutations` from `gtools` package

An example:

```
bases=c('A','T','G','C')
#load library
library("gtools")
permutations(n=length(bases),r=3,v=bases,repeats.allowed=T)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,] "A"  "A"  "A" 
 [2,] "A"  "A"  "C" 
 [3,] "A"  "A"  "G" 
 [4,] "A"  "A"  "T" 
 [5,] "A"  "C"  "A" 
 [6,] "A"  "C"  "C" 
 [7,] "A"  "C"  "G" 
 [8,] "A"  "C"  "T" 
 [9,] "A"  "G"  "A" 
[10,] "A"  "G"  "C" 
[11,] "A"  "G"  "G" 
[12,] "A"  "G"  "T" 
[13,] "A"  "T"  "A" 
[14,] "A"  "T"  "C" 
[15,] "A"  "T"  "G" 
[16,] "A"  "T"  "T" 
[17,] "C"  "A"  "A" 
[18,] "C"  "A"  "C" 
[19,] "C"  "A"  "G" 
[20,] "C"  "A"  "T" 
[21,] "C"  "C"  "A" 
[22,] "C"  "C"  "C" 
[23,] "C"  "C"  "G" 
[24,] "C"  "C"  "T" 
[25,] "C"  "G"  "A" 
[26,] "C"  "G"  "C" 
[27,] "C"  "G"  "G" 
[28,] "C"  "G"  "T" 
[29,] "C"  "T"  "A" 
[30,] "C"  "T"  "C" 
[31,] "C"  "T"  "G" 
[32,] "C"  "T"  "T" 
[33,] "G"  "A"  "A" 
[34,] "G"  "A"  "C" 
[35,] "G"  "A"  "G" 
[36,] "G"  "A"  "T" 
[37,] "G"  "C"  "A" 
[38,] "G"  "C"  "C" 
[39,] "G"  "C"  "G" 
[40,] "G"  "C"  "T" 
[41,] "G"  "G"  "A" 
[42,] "G"  "G"  "C" 
[43,] "G"  "G"  "G" 
[44,] "G"  "G"  "T" 
[45,] "G"  "T"  "A" 
[46,] "G"  "T"  "C" 
[47,] "G"  "T"  "G" 
[48,] "G"  "T"  "T" 
[49,] "T"  "A"  "A" 
[50,] "T"  "A"  "C" 
[51,] "T"  "A"  "G" 
[52,] "T"  "A"  "T" 
[53,] "T"  "C"  "A" 
[54,] "T"  "C"  "C" 
[55,] "T"  "C"  "G" 
[56,] "T"  "C"  "T" 
[57,] "T"  "G"  "A" 
[58,] "T"  "G"  "C" 
[59,] "T"  "G"  "G" 
[60,] "T"  "G"  "T" 
[61,] "T"  "T"  "A" 
[62,] "T"  "T"  "C" 
[63,] "T"  "T"  "G" 
[64,] "T"  "T"  "T"
```

Comment: I don't think this generates the expected result, say for this case it will not give me the list of 4^3= 64 k-mers

Comment: Answer changed according to this